# What does reference with a template type mean?

Tags: c++, templates, types, std

In the code that I try to understand I see constructs like this: `ref<date>(entry)`. Can anybody, please, explain what it can mean.

I assume that we create a reference to the `entry` object but how `date` type is used. For example `ref<date>(entry)` and `ref<location>(entry)` will return different values. How does it work?

Comment: @sftrabbit, I am not sure. In the code I have `using namespace std;` and no other name spaces are used in this way. Moreover, in front of `ref` I do not have `::`, so I assume it comes from the `std` name space.

Comment: @sftrabbit I was asking my self the same question, but `std::ref` should not require an explicit template argument.

Comment: What’s the type / initialisation of `entry`?

Answer (score 3):

If you have `using namespace std;` and are including the `<functional>` header, this is referring to the [`std::ref`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref) function.

`std::ref` is a function that will create a [`std::reference_wrapper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper) wrapping the object you pass. The whole point of `std::ref` is that you *don't* have to give the template argument because it can be deduced. So if you want a reference to `entry`, then you should just do:

```
std::ref(entry)
```

It's a convenience function that saves you having to type redundant type names when creating a `std::reference_wrapper`. If you do it manually, you would have to do:

```
std::reference_wrapper<date>(entry)
```

That's because `std::reference_wrapper` is a template class and template class parameters cannot be deduced in this way.

Answer (score 2):

The [`std::ref`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref) function template is used to create an `std::reference_wrapper` for a certain object. This allows passing an object by reference to a function template even though the function template takes the corresponding argument by value:

For instance:

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T t)
{
    t = 42;
}

int x = 0;
foo(std::ref(x));
std::cout << x; // Will print 42
```

Notice, that function `foo()` above is quite a stupid function, and I wrote it just for illustrative purpose. More often, you will find `std::ref` or `std::cref` being used in combination with [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind), which by default creates a *copy* of the arguments you provide:

```
template<typename T>
void bar(T v1, T& v2)
//              ^
//              Second argument accepted by reference this time...
{
    v2 = v1 + 42;
}

int x = 0;
auto f = std::bind(bar, 0, ref(x));
//                         ^^^
//                         ...but without this, a copy of x would be created!

f(x);
std::cout << x; // Will print 42
```

Also notice, that you do not normally specify a template argument explicitly for `std::ref` or `std::cref`, but you rather let the function template deduce it.